# Graphing out the sensor data in a C-based application

Tags: sensor, c

So my setup basically includes STM32 as an MCU to which a temperature sensor and an nrfl2401 radio module are hooked. On the receiving end, I am thinking of having a Raspberry pi as an MCU hooked to the radio module acting as the receiver, and the idea is to continuously send temperature data to the receiver and graph it out on a server running on an RPI.

The code is written in C, and i'm wondering how could I link up the server and graphing aspect to the application running on the RPI? The libraries I have seen online are either in JS or Python.

Comment: Ah, let me see. nrf2401 talks serial, so Rpi should have not problem getting data from nrf2401. Once receiving the data, Rpi can use python or other libraries to do the graphics.

Comment: right. so receiving data and graphing should be independent of each other, yeah? so I thought if I could just have my application store the data as it's received into a CSV, and then have the JS code plot it out in real time. also, do you have any suggestions for any graphing tool? i have looked at PapaParse but haven't been able to run..

Comment: Well, it depends on what do you mean by "real time". If what you want is simple things like histogram, you can use JS or python to DIY a graphics tool. If your graphics is complicated, you might try Spyder, among many other similar tools.